# Paypal REST api support for China

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I just come across this link

https://www.paypal-forward.com/innovation/paypal-s-new-rest-apis-available-globally/

and was wondering where i can see list of country supported and currency supported, as when i login to my developer account, the sandbox account is still limited to few countries.

My use case is around providing payment using paypal in China ideally using RMB but fallback to USD will be acceptable too. Is this supported?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the countries and currencies supported by the PayPal REST Payment API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/